# How to temporarily re-parent a bone within an armature?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, parent

How do I temporarily (for a given number of frames) give a bone a new parent from within it's armature? 
My scenario is I've got a cowboy and I'm trying to get him to hold his gun. But the gun bone is already parented to the torso so it stays on the hip. How do I change the parent to the hand so he can hold it reliably until he puts it back on his hip? It's all within one object/armature.

Sorry, I'm brand new to 3D animation and I'm sure the solution is flying right over my head.

[image: Where the gun normally sits]

[image: Where the gun sits when he's holding it]

Comment: You can use technics indicated here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58983/rigging-two-handed-weapon/58988#58988. The main points are to separate the gun bone from the main armature (so that the gun has its own armature) and to use the 'influence' parameter on the bone constraint