# Animation + Rigging (again....)

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

Okay...so I know I don't really give enough information, so...
Question: When rigging for an FPS game, how should I go about this? Rig gun, parent to the main gun bone, rig arms, and make another parent? Or, like rig arms and gun and make one parent bone for them? 
And when animating, should I animate the gun, then the arms seperately and try to sync their movements, or should I make the two in one animation. 
If someone would share their typical FPS rigging method, I could try that instead of trying tons of maybe useless stuff.
Thanks!

Comment: related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58983/rigging-two-handed-weapon/58988#58988

Comment: Seeing as this seems not to be specific to Blender, you might consider asking on [Game Development](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/). Or maybe there is already an answer there waiting for you - try searching.