# How can I rig a two handed weapon that can import to Unity?

Tags: animation, rigging, unity

I have been rigging and animating characters for a while now, but I usually tend to stay away from two handed weapons for the reason I am struggling with.

I'll explain exactly what I have rigged.[image]

I started with a simple rig with two arms and a IK bone sticking out to control the arm, however, I used to rig some first person rigs a little bit ago so I decided to use one of those strategies.

One thing to note, I browsed another forum and found something that I thought would work, however, there is one thing that I disliked.  This is the forum I was talking about:
[Rigging two handed weapon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58983/rigging-two-handed-weapon)

[image]
It works, but I dislike how the bone rotates slightly when you move it.
I need it how when you move the bone, it doesn't rotate at all unless you manually rotate it.
[image]

I duplicated the arm bones, made those the IK bones then parented each original bone to the IK bones.  This actually turned out really well and I was happy with the results... until I put this into Unity.

Because the original bones aren't parented with the base skeleton, the Hand is not parented to the Forearm bone therefore making it independent from what the rest of the arm is doing.

This is what it looks like when I make a ragdoll effect in Unity.  I already went over this and I cannot have this game without ragdoll effect.

[image]

I will upload my blend file here, but this is my first time uploading a question so I don't entirely know how to do that.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: For uploads, you can use [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and add the given link to your question by [editing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/136940/edit) it.