# Hand is not glued to gun as expected

Tags: animation, armature, inverse-kinematics

I have a character mesh with a 2 handed gun held in his right arm and supported by left arm. IK and constraints are set properly as suggested here: [Rigging two handed weapon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58983/rigging-two-handed-weapon)

Still, it seems like the left hand can't keep up with the gun, making it feel like it is lagging. If I set Time Remapping from 100-100 to 100-900 (making the animation run slower), it is a lot better, but it really isn't the right way to fix it. The general concept of IK is there, the hand follows the gun nicely, but this issue completely ruins it for using it in animated renders.

[image: Weapon barrel with hand clipping through]
[image: Gun pivot is not following the Empty as supposed]

I am looking for a solution to effectively glue the left hand to the desired place on the gun. Iterations are set to maximum in case of every IK constrain.

If you need any more informations let me know.

Comment: It sounds like you've got a conflict there - 2 modifiers or constraints etc fighting over  control of the hand or gun?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if yes, I don't know where exactly. I'll attach more pictures of the armature, the gun and each constraints as soon as possible so you will have a better overview of the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Solution: The gun and body armatures were separate, so I deleted the original gun armature and created one inside the body armature. Using IK that targets the last bone of the gun and uses the gun mesh as a pole. I could achieve an almost, if not completely perfect result.
Took me way too long to find it myself, so I'll leave it here for others, who suffer from the same problem.