# Rigging two-handed weapon in Blender 2.8

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints, inverse-kinematics

I'm having trouble with rigging a two-handed weapon in Blender 2.82. Basically, I want to achieve this:

[image: Two-handed weapon rigging]

Such gif was retrieved from a previous [questions and answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58983/rigging-two-handed-weapon), but the solution applied for a Blender version lower from 2.8 so does not apply the same.

I think I did something wrong. I followed the solution propposed by @moonboots. However, when I move the gun, the hands do not follow it in terms of translation, only rotation. What could be?

[image]

Comment: have you tried with a Child Of constraint for both the 2 hands?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the nature of the suggestion. I'm not that experienced with rigging. So, how could I implement your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a root bone for your gun, create 2 children bones, one for handle 1, one for handle 2:

[image]

In *Pose* mode, give each of your hand controller a *Child Of* constraint, with the handle 1 and handle 2 as *Target*, click on *Set Inverse*:

[image]

Move each controller close to the handle, move the fingers so that it looks like they are grabbing the handles, keyframe:

[image]

Move your gun, the hands should follow:

[image]

Comment: Just awesome. Works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: I got a problem in terms of translation. What could be? I edited the original question to show my issue. @moonboots

Comment: It doesn't sound like you have IK arms, while @moonboots 's solution assumes you do.  Try giving your arms IK controllers, then child-of the IK controllers to the gun.

Comment: Yes what I called controller bones are the IK target, is it your problem?

Comment: Once again, I'm sorry for looking like an annoying noob (which in basic terms, I am) but I'm not sure how to do the IK arms thing. I mean, I know there's the modifier, but don't know how to use it.@Nathan @moonboots

Comment: follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0bFrZn8xlLw

Comment: I think I got it. Was like adding a "Child Of" constraint, but instead "Inverse Kinematics" with the target bone, right?

Comment: IK are for the lowerarms. You need to create a bone that will be the target of the IK (that will control the lowerarm), in my screenshots it's the vertical bone under the wrist. You'll give these controllers a Child Of constraint so that they will be themselves controlled by the bones of the gun

Comment: @moonboots I achieved my objective. Thank you so much for the advicing.