# I want to attach 2 handed Sword to my rig in blender

Tags: animation, rigging

I want to attach 2 handed Sword to my Rig

so I was looking for a Tutorials and I found this article [Here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196709/rigging-two-handed-weapon-in-blender-2-8)

it works but the issue that I face that I want the hands static to the sword while moving
the IK controller on both Hands the left and the right and when I curve the sword it will curve both hands I am kind of new to blender I was messing with the IK and the parent but
I didn't achieve my goal

like this example
[image: Text]

My issue
[image: Text]

I want to mine to be like the example that I provide

(Sorry for my English if you don't understand me)

Comment: To me, it looks like the hands-to-sword bones system works as intended, but the hands are moving additively. I suspect the issue comes from your IK setup, it looks like the hands bones still inherits rotations from the arm. Please [share your file](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3051/53447) so that we can check your setup and provide an adapted answer.